# Cannot retrive a group from Scala Regex match

Tags: regex, scala

I am struggling with regexps in Scala (2.11.5), I have a followin string to parse (example):

```
val string = "http://sth.com/sth/56,57597,14058913,Article_title,,5.html"
```

I want to extract third numeric value in the string above (it needs to be third after a slash because there can be other groups following), in order to do that I have the following regex pattern:

```
val pattern = """\/\d+,\d+,(\d+)""".r
```

I have been trying to retrieve the group for the third sequence of digits, but nothing seems to work for me.

```
val matchList = pattern.findAllMatchIn(string).foreach(println)
val matchListb = pattern.findAllIn(string).foreach(println)
```

I also tried using matching pattern.

```
string match {
    case pattern(a) => println(a)
    case _ => "What's going on?"
}
```

and got the same results. Either whole regexp is returned or nothing.

Is there an easy way to retrieve a group form regexp pattern in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group` method of `scala.util.matching.Regex.Match` to get the result.

```
val string = "http://sth.com/sth/56,57597,14058913,Article_title,,5.html"
val pattern = """\/\d+,\d+,(\d+)""".r

val result = pattern.findAllMatchIn(string)  // returns iterator of Match
                    .toArray                 
                    .headOption              // returns None if match fails
                    .map(_.group(1))         // select first regex group

// or simply

val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(string).map(_.group(1)) 

// result = Some(14058913)
// result will be None if the string does not match the pattern.

// if you have more than one groups, for instance:
// val pattern = """\/(\d+),\d+,(\d+)""".r 
// result will be Some(56)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is usually the easiest way to do it, but it requires a match on the full string, so you'll have to prefix and suffix your regex pattern with `.*`:

```
val string = "http://sth.com/sth/56,57597,14058913,Article_title,,5.html"
val pattern = """.*\/\d+,\d+,(\d+).*""".r
val pattern(x) = string
// x: String = 14058913
```